# COBOL display line structure

Tags: cobol

I am trying to create a display line structure with FILLER clauses in between the data items within OpenCOBOL but I am having a hard time finding out how to do it. I am a beginner.

I tried:

```
   **Display City Names          
           DISPLAY "Montreal" line 3 col 10.
           DISPLAY "Ottawa" line 3 col 10.
           DISPLAY "Toronto" line 3 col 10.
           DISPLAY "Kingston" line 3 col 10.
           DISPLAY "Cornwall" line 3 col 10.
           
      **Display Average Temperatures Calculated
           DISPLAY 
           "Here are the average temperatures for cities in the area".
           DISPLAY "C" LINE 4 COLUMN 10.
           DISPLAY "C" LINE 4 COLUMN 10.
           DISPLAY "C" LINE 4 COLUMN 10.
           DISPLAY "C" LINE 4 COLUMN 10.
           DISPLAY "C" LINE 4 COLUMN 10.
           DISPLAY "Press any key to continue . . .".
```

and I expected:

[image]

Comment: I'd create WORKING-STORAGE areas to display the cities and temperatures and use one DISPLAY for each line.

Comment: In this case 2 `working storage lines1 could be used as Gilbert said. Also the columns be different in the displays or is that a typing error in the question i.e `DISPLAY "Montreal" line 3 col 10.
           DISPLAY "Ottawa" line 3 col 20.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Gilbert and Bruce. I have added a line to my working storage and I was able to line them up as shown in the picture above. I am now attempting to figure out how to use the filler to create the spaces in between each city and the temperature. I have added a filler below each city in my WORKING STORAGE with a filler listed below each city. However, it seems like I am still not doing something right as it  is not being reflected within my results.

Comment: We do have the expected results, but not the actual ones. Your sample code `DISPLAY`s all cities / "C" at the same place, so that's not going to work...
Where do you stand now (and why do you use a totally outdated OpenCOBOL instead of its successor GnuCOBOL)?

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   
   01 CITIES.
       05 CITY1     PIC X(10) VALUE 'Montreal'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05 CITY2     PIC X(10) VALUE 'Ottawa'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05 CITY3     PIC X(10) VALUE 'Toronto'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05 CITY4     PIC X(10) VALUE 'Kingston'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(5)  VALUE SPACES.
       05 CITY5     PIC X(10) VALUE 'Cornwall'. 

   01 TEMPS.
       05 TEMP1     PIC 99.9  VALUE '10.8'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(11) VALUE 'C'.
       05 TEMP2     PIC 99.9  VALUE '12.3'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(11) VALUE 'C'.
       05 TEMP3     PIC 99.9  VALUE '14.1'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(11) VALUE 'C'.
       05 TEMP4     PIC 99.9  VALUE '13.8'.
       05 FILLER    PIC X(11) VALUE 'C'.
       05 TEMP5     PIC 99.9  VALUE '11.9'.       
  
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN-PROCEDURE.
  
        DISPLAY CITIES.
        DISPLAY TEMPS.
        STOP RUN.
```

Comment: I note that the code is missing the final `05 FILLER    PIC X(11) VALUE 'C'.` needed to provide the "C" after `TEMP5`.

Comment: I think you should not use `PIC 99.9` but `PIC Z9.9` to avoid leading zero and maybe a `-`, in case the temperature will be below zero.